# How do I trigger suggestion(s) in VSCode in Catalina?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[This](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) tells me that I could use `⌃ + Space` combination in order to display suggestions for my code. However, `ctrl + Space` ( `^` key is `ctrl` as far as I know) only seems to change the input language keyboard in my system. Nothing else seems to work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Try `Option + Escape`, on mac.

The mac keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for switching input sources overrides the VSCode one. Because of this, VSCode added a new keybinding just for mac, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>

This is actually called intellisense, and the new keyboard shortcut was added in the [November 2019 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41).

Comment: Why do I keep forgetting this keystroke?

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the macOS shortcut in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts.

Alternatively you can set up a custom keybinding for this command in VS Code, so that it no longer conflicts with your system shortcut. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

Comment: Thanks very much, it turns out that I wasn't aware of this conflict with the system shortcut. Maybe Apple introduced it in Catalina.

Comment: You need to restart VSCode after changing System Shortcuts

Answer (score 5):

Recently, ⌘I (i.e. <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) is also a by default key binding for triggering suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

On MacOS Ventura,

- Go to System Settings
- Select **Keyboard** on the Left panel
- Select "Keyboard Shortcuts"

[image]

- Select **Input Sources** and toggle the switch labelled "Select the previous input source".

[image]

- **Quit** vscode and relaunch