# How to get flutter property list in vscode editor in Mac m1?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get properties list like below example

[image]

According to a youtube tutorial , I have to press control + space to get this list. After try in my computer it's changing my language.

[image]

Here I'm trying to get property list of Scaffold class.

```
home: Scaffold(
       //I'm trying here
),
```

I also installed flutter and dart extensions.

My extension list

[image]

Explorar tab

[image]

Comment: did you install flutter extension?

Comment: @NazmulHasan yes.

Comment: will you please add your codes and left side's explorer ss?

Comment: I already shared my explorer and also mentioned where I'm trying.

Comment: You've added extensions tab. I said the explorer tab.

Comment: @NazmulHasan sorry I added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trigger suggestion(s) in VSCode in Catalina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505662/how-do-i-trigger-suggestions-in-vscode-in-catalina)

Comment: @frippe Thank you.